# Prevent websites from automatically scrolling the view

Tags: firefox, browser, scrolling

I use Firefox. On a few websites when I click on a button that expands a list or something similar, the website automatically scrolls so that the newly expanded element is in the middle of the screen.

How do I disable this feature in the browser and completely prevent websites from scrolling the view? Preferably this would also disable any custom scrolling implementations from websites.

Comment: An answer will probably be different for each website.

Comment: Short of fully disabling Javascript?  You don't.